# How can I sort a text file of winners' scores in order to print the top 5 winners?

Tags: python, sorting

I am very new to coding.
I am currently creating a dice game where players roll their die in 5 rounds, and the player who score the most points in total is the winner.
I am able to write the Score and the player name in an external file, "Winners.txt" and it looks like:

```
25 - Hisham

20 - Jonothan

30 - Hi

28 - Lo

26 - Jonothan

32 - Hello
```

Is there anyway I can reorder the list so the score is descending?
And how can I then print the top 5 winners?
Thanks

Comment: Could you show the code that you have tried till now.

Comment: Please share the code that is used,  because it's where the modification should be

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
with open('Winners.txt') as f:
    l=f.readlines() #read the file and save lines to list
   
l=[i.split() for i in l] #split lines
l=[ i for i in l if i!=[]] #remove empty lines
l.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]), reverse=True) #sort lines by number descending

result=l[:5] #get the first 5

for i in result:
    print(i[0], i[-1]) #print first and last items of each line
```

Output:

```
32 Hello
30 Hi
28 Lo
26 Jonothan
25 Hisham
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you solution, it worked perfectly. if you wouldn't mind, could you please explain what each part of the code means, would help me significantly for my understanding in coding, Thanks!

Comment: Great, happy to help! I added some comments inside my code. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

We'll need your code if you wish to make modifications in it only. Assuming that you just need to sort the names based on score, here's the code

```py
file =open('winners.txt')
winner= file.read().split()
dictWin = {}

del winner[1::3]           #deletes '-' symbol

for i in range(0,len(winner),2):
    dictWin[winner[i]]=winner[i+1]

print(dictWin[max(dictWin.keys())])
```

You can use dictWin to get more specific data such as lowest score and rewrite sorted data in winners.txt

Comment: Thank you, but how do I get it to print the score next to the name? And also how to print the top 5 winners and their scores?